# Custom Page Template for Blog Posts just show blank screen

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a wordpress theme which making a custom Page Template for Blog Posts just show blank screen when testing it. You can check out script below:

**blog.php**

```
<

?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package testing
 */

/*
Template Name: blog
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

        <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How I can make show the blog posts on custom template page?

I making own wordpress theme used [this generator](http://underscores.me/)

Comment: Is it for display a single blog post ? . Though I think yes as it has comment functionality. Still wanna be sure

Comment: @abhisekMalakar no, it isn't for single post but display for all posts. I already removed that's comment function. Thanks for heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below line of code just before while loop.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=10&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); 
?>
```